# How to set the defaultView of fullCalendar in Meteor?

Tags: meteor, fullcalendar

I am using [fullCalendar](https://atmospherejs.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar) package to add calendar in my project. By default the view shows by months and I want to change it to weekly bases.

From fullCalendar [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Available_Views/), [agendaWeek](https://fullcalendar.io/views/agendaWeek/)is what I am looking for.

I tried the following (didn't work):

```
$("#calendar").fullCalendar({
        defaultView: 'agendaWeek'
});
```

When I create button and add the following event to it:

```
Template.appointments.events({
    'click #check': function(e, t) {
        e.preventDefault()
        // console.log(Requests.find({}).fetch())
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'agendaWeek');
    }
});
```

It works and the calendar changes.

My question is, how can set the calendar view to `agendaWeek` by default?

It would even be better if there is a way to make it similar to the calendar in their [official page](https://fullcalendar.io/views/agendaWeek/) were there are three buttons (month, week, and day) buttons to choose from.

Comment: if you want like the calendar in the official page, do a view source on that page and see how they coded it. Or any of the other demos. You do you realise you can inspect the code of any public website you like using your browser tools?

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay', // gets you the three button tabs that you were looking for, similar to the demo 
    },
    defaultView: 'agendaWeek' // default view is agendaWeek
});
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/jL5wash6/) is the jsfiddle for it.

Comment: I don't know why its not working in meteor, I created 3 normal buttons for month, week, and day and triggered `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('changeView', 'viewType');` when a button clicked. Even though its working, but it would be better if i could do it as you mentioned,but for some reason, it doesn't work in Meteor

Comment: Why do you want to redo what they already offer out of the box?

Comment: I don't want to redo it, I am asking why it is not working in Meteor? Maybe there is other way of doing it. Because your solution doesn't work (in Meteor)

Comment: It very much works as intended in meteor. I sure hope you've put it in the right place (inside ```onRendered```)

Comment: yes, It is inside onRendered, are you using the same package I am using? or how did you go about using the fullCalendar?

Comment: I'm using what's available on [atmospherejs](https://atmospherejs.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar) (```meteor add fullcalendar:fullcalendar```)

Comment: I am using the same as well. This is confusing

Comment: I think you might want to  take a step back, and do a simpler app just to get a hang of what is going on. Maybe put it up on github and we'll take a look to see what the problem might be. For starters, you can create a new meteor app and add fullcalendar and see if it works there.